# taking 3 numbers and printing the average but giving me error

Tags: python

taking 3 numbers and printing the average but giving me error

```
num,num1,num2=int(input("Enter 3 numbers : ").split(","))

num + num1 + num2 / 3

print(f"Average of 3 numbers is {num + num1 + num2 / 3}")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Comment: First and foremost, I would post the error that you are getting...

Comment: You should use (num1+num2+num3)/3. Simple rule, first add all and then divide to get the average

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this-

```
num,num1,num2=map(int, input("Enter 3 numbers : ").split(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this :

```
num, num1, num2=map(int, raw("Enter 3 numbers : ").split(","))

print(f"Average of 3 numbers is {(num + num1 + num2) / 3}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Your error is in the first line - you're getting three numbers from the command line but int can only take in one number at a time. Try:

```
num,num1,num2=[int(i) for i in input("Enter 3 numbers : ").split(",")]

# the next line you included does nothing and you can remove it if you want
(num+num1+num2)/3

print(f"Average of 3 numbers is {(num+num1+num2)/3}")
```

You also forgot parentheses before your division and would have got an incorrect average - I've fixed that too.

Comment: Why put 1/3 three times instead of just once below the sum

Comment: Your second line is useless: you calculate something and throw away the result immediately, as you don't affect it to anything.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille you're right - I was just changing his example minimally. Am going to edit to reflect

Comment: @Bazingaa working quickly and didn't want to test that it worked with parens - I'm not very au fait with the format syntax, and anyway it was not material to the original question asked